# Differences of two real-valued periodic function is zero in limit

Tags: real-analysis

Given $f, g \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a periodic function. If $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(f(x) - g(x)\right) = 0$, prove that $f = g$.

Comment: Can $f$ and $g$ have arbitrary periods?